# Recommandation for a 360 degrees video camera for developers

Tags: video

I'm a developer and I'm intending to develop a camera based surveillance software.

The simplest way is to try and pick a 360 degrees video camera. I found some models but the problem is that the recorded/real-time flow videos are only readable by the manufacturer's software (example: [GoPano](http://www.gopano.com/store/)).

Is there any 360° video camera device that is shipped with tools for developers so that we can build our own softwares ? Are there alternatives ?

The idea is to have a real time video flow that could be consumable by any platform (browser, iOS SDK, Android SDK, etc.).

Regards.

Comment: Interesting.  Definitely interested in the answer.  Also interested to see if it is considered on-topic here or not.

Comment: It's definitely on topic since I'm just asking for the device and its API. I believe this is the stackexchange's website where I should ask.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is to use a camera which you can attach a "fish-eye" (wide-angle) lens to.

These can be very expensive though and typically target professional photographers.

You have also this lens for iPhone:
http://www.pixeet.com/fisheye-lens

The other option is to contact the manufacturer of the camera you already looked at and ask if they are willing to give you the protocol specifications (or you can try reverse-engineer the protocol communication).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is theorically what I want. This is why I asked my question in the goal to find a concrete answer.

Comment: Also check their main page for panoramic solution: http://www.pixeet.com/